# How does this zipfile print a message to my console when it's unzipped?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface, unzip

I downloaded a font from FontSpace.com

and unzipped it using `unzip my_font.zip`

The following was then printed:

```
Archive:  kimberly-geswein_just-realize.zip

  _____           _   ____                       
 |  ___|__  _ __ | |_/ ___| _ __   __ _  ___ ___ 
 | |_ / _ \| '_ \| __\___ \| '_ \ / _` |/ __/ _ \
 |  _| (_) | | | | |_ ___) | |_) | (_| | (_|  __/
 |_|  \___/|_| |_|\__|____/| .__/ \__,_|\___\___|.com
                           |_|                   

    Visit us at http://www.fontspace.com for more
    information on this font, or for thousands of 
    more fonts!


  inflating: JustRealize.ttf         
  inflating: JustRealizeBold.ttf     
 extracting: KGFonts-TOU.txt
```

How was this achieved? I don't mean the unzipping, I mean the printing of the advertisement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line you can do this with command `zipnote` which generally comes with the `zip` command.

From the manpage:

```
Example:
     zipnote foo.zip > foo.tmp
     ed foo.tmp
     ... then you edit the comments, save, and exit ...
     zipnote -w foo.zip < foo.tmp
```

The trick is to put the "comment" at the end of that `.tmp` file that is read back into the `.zip` by the `zipnote` command.